# Filter Camel Headers before calling external API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have defined by HeaderFilterStrategy like this

```
@Configuration
public class HeaderFilterConfiguration extends DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy {
    @Bean("exchangeObjectFilter")
    public void removeExchangeObject() {
        setFilterOnMatch(false);
        Set<String> filters = getOutFilter();
        filters.add("orchestrationExchange");
        setOutFilter(filters);
    }

}
```

and I am using this filtering strategy using this code

```
from("direct:mock")
                .streamCaching()
                .routeId("orchestration-token")
                .routeDescription("Invokes GET token details to call external endpoints")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.getMimeType()))
                .setBody(header(REQUEST_BODY))
                .toD("http://my-okta-route.com?headerFilterStrategy=#exchangeObjectFilter")
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, TokenResponse.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Successfully processed token. Token response::${body}");
```

But when I am printing the exchange object it still contains all the headers without any filtering. I have checked all the camel resources but couldn't find how to apply defaultheaderfilterstrategy in dsl.

Comment: as far as I remember the strategy is only in charge to filter headers before they are mapped to the external resource but does not remove them from the exchange (so you need to check what the http service receives to check if the headers are filtered).

to remove the header from the exchange you can use removeHeader/removeHeaders

Answer (score 1):

The HeaderFilterStrategy "removes headers from the communication while not removing them from the Exchange". Check this [FAQ](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-avoid-sending-some-or-all-message-headers.html#Howtoavoidsendingsomeorallmessageheaders-UseHeaderFilterStrategy) as a reference.

When I need to remove headers from the exchange, I use the [Remove Header](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/removeHeader-eip.html) or [Remove Headers](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/removeHeaders-eip.html) EIP.

Example 1: remove all JMS headres using wildcard

```java
from("direct:update-document")
  .removeHeaders("JMS*")
  .to("direct:store-test-result")
```

Example 2: remove all JMS headres using wildcard

```java
from("direct:update-document")
  .removeHeaders("*")
  .to("direct:store-test-result")
```